# Issue overloading >> and << operator in C++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

So I have a few really weird things going on.  If I try to run the program with the default constructor, it tells me that it can't find a match for the >> overload.  And when I pass anything to the << overload it's just spitting out trash.  My source is below.

```
#include "Employe.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Employe unEmploye("");
    cin >> unEmploye;
    cout << unEmploye << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Employe.h

```
//Employe.h
#ifndef EMPLOYE_H
#define EMPLOYE_H
#include <iostream>

class Employe {
protected:
    char * nom;

public:
    Employe();
    Employe(char *);

    void setNom(char * _nom);
    char * getNom();

    //over load
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream  &input, Employe &e);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Employe &);

};
#endif
```

And lastly employe.cpp

```
//employe.cpp
#include<cString>
#include "Employe.h"
using namespace std;


void Employe::setNom(char * _nom) {
    this->nom = _nom;
}

char * Employe::getNom() {
    return this->nom;
}

Employe::Employe() {
    nom = new char[];
    nom = "";
}

Employe::Employe(char * _nom) {

    nom = _nom;

}

istream &operator>>(istream  &input, Employe &e){
    char temp[1024]=" ";
    input >> temp;
    e.setNom(temp);
    return input;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Employe const  &e) {
    out << "Je suis un employer, et mon nom est :" << e.nom << ".";
    return out;
}
```

Example input:  Test
Example output: 
[image: Test]

If the program is run with the default constructor and not an empty string, I get the error: Error  1   error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Employe (__cdecl *)(void)' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: If you mean `Employe unEmploye();`, you are a victim of the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Declare it as `Employe unEmploye;` instead.

Comment: Full disclosure:  This wasn't even my code, but I absolutely didn't think to look there.  That solves the not compiling when run without a constructor issue, now just the ostream giving me junk...

Comment: As for the junk you are setting `nom` to a local variable (`temp`), not copying the contents. When you later read from `nom` you invoke undefined behavior. Use a `std::string` instead.

Comment: `nom = new char[]; nom = "";` won't compile either (and if it did, it is an insta-memory-leak). Can you *please* post *real* code ?

Comment: Fixed that LOC.  Unfortunately I'm stuck using char pointers, so I can't really use an std::string.

Comment: `Unfortunately I'm stuck using char pointers` Change jobs / school. Seriously, get out now while you still can!

Comment: Hahaha, this isn't even my homework.  I work doing Java development and I'm trying to help a friend, but this abysmal piece of code is the tip of the iceberg compared to the shit I've seen this semester.

Comment: @WhozCraig:  Thanks for the catch on that bit of code.

Comment: `I work doing Java development`  I guess that explains why there are no calls to `delete[]` in your code.  Your Employe class has memory leaks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Not my code, but I appreciate you pointing it out.